# Will Entity Framework 6 function normally within Task.Run() statements?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, task-parallel-library

My question is simple, if I perform a read or write within a Task.Run in order to make my method asynchronous, will it work as a normal bit of code would, or is there something within EF that bans this practice?

For example:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    var data = _context.KittenLog.ToList();
}
```

I have an uneasy feeling that doing this will open a can of worms, but I can't find anything on google about combining the two.

Comment: Run the code and find out.  You've already written it, after all.  Of course, there's never any good reason to do this in the first place, but you can still find out if you're able to easily enough.

Comment: All your code does is basically to push the query that retrieves the data from the database to a thread pool thread and since an EF query may be issued on any thread, why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Well if I run it I'm sure it'll work. But there could be deadlocking type issues or problems with inserts. Essentially I'm asking if it's task-safe. You can't determine if something is thread-safe just by testing it a couple of times and I suspect tasks is the same.

Comment: Why can't you just use the ToListAsync method?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: *Why* do you want to use `Task.Run` in the first place? To avoid blocking, without even wasting a thread, use `ToListAsync()`. `Task.Run` won't make the data load faster, it will still be a blocking operation that will waste a thread. Inserts are a *different* matter. Nothing is as fast as `SqlBulkInsert`, by orders of magnitude. ORMs simply aren't built for bulk operations. It's like using tweezers to move a truckload of gravel

Comment: Multiple inserts in parallel will block each other, waste many connections and a a lot of network bandwidth *and* generate a lot of transaction log records. A BULK INSERT operation like the one performed by SqlBulkCopy though will use minimal logging and pass all lines in a single stream of records to the server over a single connection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As part of an MVC application with async controllers, I was wondering if putting EF operations into tasks would be more efficient

Comment: @NibblyPig the asynchronous operations like `ToListAsync` already use tasks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yes, you could. But there is no need to wrap it in a call to `Task.Run` since it has native async support, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819165(v=vs.113).aspx#Making it asynchronous

In you case it will become something like:

```
var data = await _context.KittenLog.ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

There a some things to consider. Like the context can only handle one async operation at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this. It's exactly what I need.